# Autofac unable to resolve between two constructors when one is clearly more specific

Tags: c#, autofac

If we register a delegate as a component, the AutowiringParam take as much priority as a NamedParameter when resolving!

Here's a boiled down example:

```
public class AParam { }
public class BParam : IParam { }

public interface IParam { }

public interface IAThing { }
public class AThing : IAThing
{
    public AThing(AParam aParam) { }
    public AThing(BParam anotherParam) { }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IContainer c = (new ContainerBuilder()).Build();

    var anotherBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
    anotherBuilder.RegisterType<AThing>().As<IAThing>().InstancePerDependency();
    anotherBuilder.Register((context, parm) => new BParam()).As<BParam>().InstancePerDependency();
    anotherBuilder.Update(c);

    object aParam = new AParam();

    //Throws exception, it's unable to decide which constructor to use....
    var instance = c.Resolve(typeof(IAThing), new[] {new NamedParameter("aParam", aParam) });
}
```

In this case, I'm specifying that I want exactly the NamedParameter "aParam", but the AutowiritingParameter can fill in for BParam, so it doesn't know which constructor to pick (as they are both of equal parameter length).

How do I do it so that Autofac prioritizes the specific constructor with the named parameter I mentioned? There's no reason why I would want my parameter ignored, which would be the case if it uses the AutowiringParameter.

I could use "UsingConstructor", but as soon as BParam derives from AParam we get back to the same ambiguity. 
Here I am clearly asking for the constructor with the named parameter.
Any ideas?

Edit:

Using a default parameter in your constructor can make Autofac just ignore the user-specified-named-parameter entirely, with no error and you wont notice!

```
public class AThing : IAThing
{
    public AThing(AParam aParam) { }
    public AThing(BParam anotherParam, bool def = true) { }
}
```

Comment: I notice that your `Resolve` uses `typeof(IAThing)` but isn't it the concrete class `AThing` you're trying to specify the constructor for? Also, does [this](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#selection-of-an-implementation-by-parameter-value) offer you any help? It also says "A cleaner, type-safe syntax can be achieved if a delegate to create instances is declared and a delegate factory is used." You might be able to solve this with a delegate and delegate factory.

Comment: Hi Erik,
Well in general, we use Autofac for dependency injection, so it might not be AThing exactly we're trying to resolve (perhaps a test mock-up), but definitely the constructor with a named parameter "aParam". 

I don't see why Autofac assigns the same "specificity" (if you will) to the "aParam" constructor as the constructor using the "AutowiringParameter"
It used to work in older versions of Autofac :/ Its sort of ignoring I wanted a specific parameter name (typed parameter results in the same issue btw)
Thanks for your reply

Comment: It's an anti-pattern for your application components to have multiple constructors, as explained in detail [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: @Steven Thanks Steven, I'll give that a read. In general though, this is a trivial version of what is otherwise a humongous code-base, supporting multiple applications, and I'm just fixing it. 

I stand by my statement that "user-specified param" > autowiring param > default param.

My parameter could be ignored if there's a constructor with 2 autowiring parameters, and I would not immediately find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure you can really win in the current situation. What's "clearly more specific" to you isn't *necessarily* 100% more specific - once you've provided the parameter, Autofac takes that provided parameter along with the autowired parameters and tries to determine, given all the information available, which constructors it can fulfill. All parameters being equal - whether they came from registration time (`builder.RegisterType<T>().WithParameter(...)`), resolve time (`scope.Resolve<T>(...)`), or autowired - which constructor should it invoke?

If there was a precedence, like parameter X is more important than parameter Y, it could actually start getting pretty complicated and create some hard to troubleshoot behavior. Does a resolve-time parameter take precedence over a registration-time parameter? Can you override that behavior? Why or why not? It gets messy.

Anyway, that's why it's behaving like this and will probably continue to be that way into the future.

However, you have a couple of options:

**Option 1 -`UsingConstructor`**: You can just specify that the constructor to use in tests is the one that takes `BParam` if that's always how it is.

```
builder.RegisterType<AThing>()
  .As<IAThing>()
  .UsingConstructor(typeof(BParam));
```

I was going to suggest a potential ability to create a custom `IConstructorSelector` but you don't get the inbound parameters there, just a list of constructors that *could be fulfilled* based on the set of parameters already provided. Not enough info to go on. See the end of this answer for more on that.

**Option 2 - Lambda registrations**: This is probably what I would do if I was you. It's based on the [example in the docs here](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#selection-of-an-implementation-by-parameter-value). It's not as one-liner to implement but it gets you the effect you want:

```
// This is the "default" behavior registration for when
// no parameters are provided. Note it's named, though, so
// the actual default registration for IAThing will be the
// lambda.
builder.RegisterType<AThing>().Named<IAThing>("default-thing");

// This is what will run when you Resolve<IAThing>()
builder.Register((ctx, p) => {
  var aorb = p
    .OfType<NamedParameter>()
    .Where(n => n.Name == "aParam")
    .FirstOrDefault();
  if (aorb != null)
  {
    // You passed the parameter so use it.
    return new AThing((BParam)aorb.Value);
  }
  else
  {
    // Use the default reflection-based registration, above.
    return ctx.ResolveNamed<IAThing>("default-thing", p);
  }
}).As<IAThing>();
```

That isn't pretty, but it gets the job done. If you have a lot of these, you could wrap some of that up into an extension method that generates the default registration ID, handles the if/else logic, and so on.

---

I think it could be valuable to enable a more functional constructor selector so that `UsingConstructor` can do more. To that end, I [opened up this issue for you](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/846) to see if that would be an interesting enhancement.

Comment: I think there's clearly higher "specificity" since I wanted to resolve with a NamedParameter explicitly. If I hadn't I would not be surprised if I get an exception (or in this case not really since the only constructor is BParam).

Autofac already tries to grab the most specific constructor (by higher length), but in this case a constructor of length 2 with two autowiring parametrs would win over my constructor with 1 parameter that I explicitly named in my resolve call.

I'm thinking sort of the same specificity rules used in CSS selectors, I don't expect it to work magically. but an idea

Comment: I think it could be argued either way, but the point of my explanation was to explain why it is how it is, not to start a side discussion. I hope my answer helps.

Comment: It does, unfortunately the application is a beast that supports a lot of underlying beasts and making a huge modification hurts. Older versions of Autofac used to work, someone updated Autofac and I just have to bite the bullet of supporting the update on this, I wouldn't have done it this way meself. 
I replied to your ticket, thanks a lot for your time